# What is Sql data conditioning?

Tags: interview, qa-role, test-data, sql

This question was asked during QA interview. What is SQL data conditioning?

Is it creating test data using SQL scripts to test different scenarios?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_conditioning

Comment: "Data conditioning is the use of data management and optimization techniques which result in the intelligent routing, optimization and protection of data for storage or data movement in a computer system. Data conditioning features enable enterprise and cloud data centers to dramatically improve system utilization and increase application performance lowering both capital expenditures and operating costs."

Comment: i read that already, but how that is related to QA. Usually DBA would do the data management & optimization. I think SQL Data Conditioning is something different.

Comment: @LP13 - when asking a question, document and link to all research you already did. Because your comment "I read that already" signals that you (1) do not know how to ask questions (2) do not care if other waste time reporting you something you already know, so (3) do not want to spend effort to make this forum better, and (4) answering your question is waste of time, because you might not upvote the answer. Of course it is completely up to you what impression you want to make.

Answer (score 4):

When someone asks me a question and I don't know the answer, I tell them I don't know the answer, and then I ask them to tell me what they think the answer is.  Maybe you should do that next time.  If you're an interview, I don't think you'll be judged *worse* for asking, since either way the interviewer already knows that you don't have the answer.  And it's entirely possible that while you're not familiar with the term they're using, you actually know something about the subject -- which is all the interviewer really cares about anyway.

Here is what a few Google searches turned up.  For seismic data, that seems to mean [applying a noise filter so that the signal is stronger](https://www.opengeosolutions.com/solutions/data-conditioning).  [A Teradata documentation page](https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035-2445%E2%80%90086K/2445ch13.15.3.html) describes data conditioning in terms of renaming database columns, or creating new fields by concatenating other fields, or assigning NULL values to a column based on certain criteria.  [This web page for a marketing company](http://www.buddemarketing.com/Services/Data-Conditioning) refers to data conditioning in terms of reconciling a part number database against the  part numbers of the company's supplies.

Based on those results, "data conditioning" seems to  refer to cleaning up a data set before making it available for processing.